# Swift DateFormatter Extract Time

Tags: xcode, swift4, dateformatter

I've been trying to return a date with just Time. I tried DateFormatter, but will always retrieve a full date for some reason.

```
//Declare Date Formatter 1
let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

//Declare Date Formatter 2
let dateFormatter2 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter2.dateFormat = "hh:mm"

//Retrieve date and set to proper date for DateFormatter
var date: Date = dateFormatter1.date(from: "2017-11-28 10:47:30")!

//Set String date to time format with dateFormatter2
let dateString = dateFormatter2.string(from: item)

           //Reseting dateFormatter1 for to only use time (could be ambiguous)
           dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "hh:mm"

           //Set date to Date
           date = dateFormatter1.date(from: dateString)!

    print("String: \(dateString)")
    print("Date: \(date)")
```

Output:

> String: 10:47
>
> Date: 2000-01-01 15:47:00 +0000
>     - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : -31565580.0

I want the Date: to be 10:47 
Is this even possible?

Comment: You date it is correct for your current Locale. +0000 means UTC time. Instead of printing the date (which uses UTC timezone) you can use date property description with locale. If you print it you will realize that your date it is correct `date.description(with: .current)`

Comment: `Date` is a moment in time. It cannot have just date information or just time information, it always has both. Only the string representation of a `Date` can omit one.

Comment: `Date` made from components such as hours, minutes, day, month, year. It can not be only time. If you have only time then it will show you default month, year and day and if you have date only then it will show you default time 00:00:00. So don't worry about it.

Comment: 10:47 can be a string by using dateFormatter but not a date object.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The Variable `date` is of type `Date` which has full date information within it. When showing it in string format you can convert it as you want, but while storing in the variable of type Date it stores the full information.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use **Date.FormatStyle**
use the below code you can add locale variable to get the correct time and customise the format also  :

```
   let birthday = Date()
   let a = birthday.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened)
   print("Birthday \(a)")
```

Desired Output is :  Birthday 10:26 PM